# What does the chat message "rp" mean at the end of a round?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

After a round of Heroes of the Storm, two players typed "rp" in chat instead of the customary "gg". One player was speaking in Spanish at the start of the round, so I assume it's just the local version of "gg" - but what does it stand for?

> [image]

A Google search in both English and Spanish turned up nothing useful because of the much more common meanings of "rp" in gaming.

Comment: Usually it means "Role Play", and in this game, it might be applicable, but I think we'd need the appropriate context for that. Eg, did the heroes win in this particular game? I.e. Diablo, Kerrigan lost in the fight?

Comment: Context: the five of us won the game (Heroes only allows team chat, not all-chat), and it was generally a friendly game (e.g. nobody was flaming in chat or misbehaving).

Comment: We won by a fairly sizable margin, though, so it's *possible* it's a variant on "RIP", although it struck me as odd that two players would use the exact same spelling.

Comment: were they in a party? maybe it's simply their "thing"

Comment: My first thoughts were "RIP" and "reported"

Comment: Or a misspell of "gg wp"

Answer (score 4):

It means "Ranked Points"

"I carried you" or "Here are your free ranked points" if you're feeling snarky

"Yay we're about to get a ton of ranked points" if you're feeling cocky

It's not a very good or well thought out replacement for "GG", but hey what can you do